# how to set a button or imagebutton in a view created by our own and its position also

Tags: android, view, canvas

is it possible to set a `button` or `imagebutton` inside a view created by our own and to set position that button or imagebutton.

```
public class TestingGraphics extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   RelativeLayout layout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setId(R.layout.main);
        setContentView(layout);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        /*----------------------------------*/
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code of the view you've created

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [ViewGroup.addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), and set the width and height in the ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before plenty. The phrase I believe you're looking for is "Dynamically adding button". It's very simple once you learn the basics of it all, and you should be able to set any of the attributes of the button dynamically (in your program) whether it be size, position, or even the onClickListener(). Look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ScrollView2.html) for a basic example. Hope it helps.